# Optimized approach for filtering an array to multiple subsets

Tags: javascript, arrays, filter

I have this array

```
const array = [ {value: 1, selected: false, highlighted: true}, 
{value: 3, selected: true, highlighted: true}, 
{value: 4, selected: false, highlighted: false}, 
{value: 2}, selected: true, highlighted: false ]
```

I want to generate three subset arrays from the above, those are *highlighted*, *selected* and *selectedHightlighted*

I can achieve that using array.filter method as follows

```
const selected = array.filter((i) => i.selected)
const highlighted = array.filter((i) => i.highlighted)
const selectedHighlighted = array.filter((i) => i.selected && selectedHighlighted)
```

my question is how can I do this in an optimal way, the above code has 3 loops, if I use something like forEach method, checking the condition inside it, and pushing the object to the corresponding array, wouldn't that be a more optimized than the above approach?

Comment: *if I use something like forEach method, checking the condition inside it, and pushing the object to the corresponding array* Sure, nothing's stopping you from coding that instead..?

Comment: What you described is better than the above code @abidh